# Is there a PyTorch function equivalent to numpy.select()?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

Example using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-5, 6)
y = np.select([x<-2, x>2], [x**3, x**2], 5)
```

I could use simple conditional statements, but I need something for parallel processing of large arrays on GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NumPy expression seems to be equivalent to recursively caling [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html):

```
y = torch.where(x<-2, x**3, torch.where(x>2, x**2, 5))
```

Which means you can implement it yourself with:

```
def select(condlist, choicelist, default=0):
    o = default
    for c, v in reversed(list(zip(condlist, choicelist))):
        o = torch.where(c, v, o)
    return o
```

If you want to write it in a  recursive fashion, you can do so with:

```
def select(c, v, d=0):
    _c, _v = c.pop(), v.pop()
    r = select(c, v, d) if len(c) else d
    return torch.where(_c, _v, r)
```

Or using a [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function:

```
def select(c, v, d=0):
    zipped = reversed(list(zip(c, v)))
    return reduce(lambda o, a: torch.where(*a, o), zipped, d)
```

All methods will yield the desired result:

```
>>> select([x<-2, x>2], [x**3, x**2], 5)
tensor([-125,  -64,  -27,    5,    5,    5,    5,    5,    9,   16,   25])
```